# How to reload a layout component in svelte?

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I have the following structure in a svelte app:

```
routes/
    ...
        +layout.svelte // Displays username
        +layout.ts // Fetch username
        /settings
            +page.svelte // Update username
            +load.svelte
```

I'm trying to rerender the username in `+layout.svelte` when the user name get's updated in `+page.svelte`. I'm trying to use `depends` and `invalidate` from svelte. https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#rerunning-load-functions-manual-invalidation

In my layout I have

```
export const load = (async ({ fetch, depends }) => {

    try {
        const user = ...;
        depends("user");

        return {
            user: await user,
        };
    }});
```

and in my update function I call :

```
invalidate("user");
```

The load function gets triggered but the component is not rerendering. Using `{key user}` is also not working. What could be the problem?

Comment: Show the code that actually renders the user, it probably is not fully reactive.

Comment: You can try invalidateAll https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-invalidateall as a first step